# How can I get code coverage for maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multi module(multiple Pom) maven project and I would like the code coverage to show in Jenkins. How can I do this?

Comment: It depends what kind of code coverage tools you are using..you can use JaCoCo in Jenkins which can also being used in Maven as a plugin which can be published on you Jenkins...

Comment: Im gonna use Jacoco the problem is I can’t get this to work with multiple poms. Singular Pom projects work fine.

Comment: Jacoco is to check code coverage based on unit test, right? So, I think checking for single project is fine. And you need to do it for all projects. If you are using Jenkins integrate with Jacoco, it helps you to do multiple steps based on your requirements.